# CSS menu takes additional space

Tags: css

I am using pure-css in order to create a menu in my small school project. 
Anyway, I have a menu I am using in all the other pages by calling

```
<jsp:include page="../menu.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

My problem is the last line of the menu, "THIS TEXT IS WAY FAR DOWN", I don't know why but the menu takes all the page and when I am including it in other pages, I need to scroll down to see the content. I changed the `div` the menu is inside background color to red, and it colors all the page in red instead only the menu. Why is that happening? Maybe because the menu is dropdown menu? any solution? To explain my issue:

[image: The problem]

**Here is my menu code:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("windows-1255");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("windows-1255");
%>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal" style="background-color: red">
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <%
            if (session.getAttribute("status") == null || session.getAttribute("status").equals("guest")) {
        %>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a
            class="pure-menu-link" href="../guest/insertUser.jsp">הרשמה לאתר
        </a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a
            class="pure-menu-link" href="../guest/Login.jsp">התחברות</a></li>
        <%
            } else {
        %>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a
            href="../guest/logout.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">התנתקות</a></li>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <%
            if (session.getAttribute("currentuser") != null) {
        %>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a class="pure-menu-link" href="#">
                <%
                    out.print(session.getAttribute("currentuser"));
                %>
        </a></li>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a
            href="../guest/contact.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">צור קשר</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a
            href="../guest/Home.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">דף ראשי</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a
            href="../guest/odot.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">אודות</a></li>
        <%
            if (session.getAttribute("status") != null && session.getAttribute("status").equals("manager")) {
        %>
        <li
            class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">מנהל</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a
                    href="../admin/selectManyForms.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">רשימת
                        לקוחות</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a
                    href="../admin/startheleteWithCheckBoxes.jsp"
                    class="pure-menu-link">מחיקת פעילות מבית ספר</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="../admin/updateSchool.jsp"
                    class="pure-menu-link">עדכונים בפעילות של בית ספר </a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a
                    href="../admin/insertInfotSchool.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">הוספה
                        לטבלה פעילות בית ספר </a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="../guest/insertUser.jsp"
                    class="pure-menu-link">הוספה לקוח</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a
                    href="../admin/deleteWithCheckboxes.jsp" class="pure-menu-link">מחיקת
                        לקוחות</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="../admin/ipus.jsp"
                    class="pure-menu-link">איפוס סקר</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <%
            if (session.getAttribute("status") != null && session.getAttribute("status").equals("member")) {
        %>
        <li
            class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">משתמש</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a class="pure-menu-link"
                    href="../member/selectManyForms.jsp">רשימת לקוחות</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a class="pure-menu-link"
                    href="../member/UpdatePassword.jsp">שינוי סיסמה</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a class="pure-menu-link"
                    href="../member/UpdateMembersMail.jsp">שינוי EMAIL</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a class="pure-menu-link"
                    href="../member/seker.jsp">סקר</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </ul>
</div>
THIS TEXT IS WAY FAR DOWN.
```

I know some text is not in English in the code, but it is just the menu content and I don't think it matters. Sorry for this

Comment: So you're wanting to know why the 'menu' is taking up the whole page? We will need your CSS code to help solve this problem.

Comment: @jbrya029 well this is my code, I use purecss and I don't have any external css code.

Comment: Mind copying and pasting the HTML directly that's rendering for us? I tried using your HTML there, but you've got some processing going on and we don't have access to the applications doing said processing...